# How to create scrapy responses without requests?

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to re-process websites downloaded previously without downloading them again.

So I want to create multiple scrapy.Response's without yielding any scrapy.Request's.

- These responses should be processed before any new downloaded response.
- Let's assume the response content (url, body, ...) is loaded from somewhere.
- The build in HTTP cache is not suitable as it would require requests ...
- I do not want the Spiders to have to take care of this.

Maybe an Extension can do it -- a Middleware would be fine, too. Minimal example:

```py
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import Response

class ReprocessSnapshotsOnSpiderOpenExtension(object):

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        self.crawler = crawler
        crawler.signals.connect(self.send_the_existing_snapshots_as_new_response, signal=signals.spider_opened)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler)

    def send_the_existing_snapshots_as_new_response(self, spider):
        print("##### now in ReprocessSnapshotsOnSpiderOpenExtension.send_the_existing_snapshots_as_new_responses()")

        response1 = Response("http://the_url_of_resp1", body=b"the body of resp1")
        response2 = Response("http://the_url_of_resp2", body=b"the body of resp2")
        # ....
        responseN = Response("http://the_url_of_respN", body=b"the body of respN")

        inject_response_somehow(response1) 
        inject_response_somehow(response2)
        # ...
        inject_response_somehow(responseN)
```

So the question is: How to implement `inject_response_somehow(...)`?

Is there a possibility to control where (before/somewhere in between/after the downloader middleware/spider middlewares) the response is injected?

Comment: Yes, I think you're going to need a custom downloader, or to switch on the HTTP cache and then populate it with your existing snapshots (I can confirm that using a fully populated cache _does not_ contact the network, so I am 99% certain it would work for you)

Comment: How do you want to process the web pages? Beautiful soup would definitely accept saved page content as inputs...

Comment: @B. Go: There are different file formats (csv, html, json, ...) and multiple Spiders. 
Therefore I would like this 'reprocessing' to be transparent w.r.t. the Spiders -- they should not know if the response is old or new.
Also, since there will be multiple Spiders from different programmers, I would like to avoid code duplication or that a programmer needs to remember to add extra code.